# Target single record in MYSQL to export as CSV in a php user interface

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv

What would be the best method to do this?

the Record is identified via a GUI and a variable $s which identifies the record ID.

could you please post resources that you have used (i.e. tutorials) that have helped you do this.

Any Help is greatly appreciated !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

use MySQL select like

```
$query = "
 SELECT  
 CONCAT('\"',ifnull(firstname,''),'\",\"',ifnull(middlename,''),'\",\"',ifnull(lastname,''),'\"')    
 FROM relatie   
 WHERE relatie.id = ".$s."   
   AND relatie.SomeOtherThing > 1  
 ORDER BY relatie.id     
 LIMIT 1;
 ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

The ifnull's are very important because otherwise null fields in a CONCAT will make the whole CONCAT to be null, suppose middlename is null, this code will output something like:
"Johan","","Smith"
Without the ifnull's it will just output nothing, because the null-middlename will make the whole concat expression null.

The `Order by` and `limit` are only needed if the id is not unique, because you said you only want one line.

Next put a CSV header in and output the line you saved in $result earlier.

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo $result."\n";
```

Comment: where would i pass my variable $s that holds the record ID?

Comment: also can the file be downloaded via a link opposed to on-page-load ?

Comment: unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in  `CONCAT('"',ifnull(firstname,''),'","',ifnull(middlename,''),'","',ifnull(lastname,''),'"')`

Comment: Well I'm not a PHP-guru, just decent in MySQL, isn't there some way to escape the `"`, so php will not choke on it but MySQL will still see `"`?  BTW put the $s in the query.

Comment: I've escaped the " in the php code by replacing them with \".

Comment: "also can the file be downloaded via a link opposed to on-page-load ?" I suggest you ask another question on that, loads of people would like to know the answer to that as well :-)